# Why are my SQL Commands not working in web app with Postgresql?

Tags: python, postgresql, cs50

I made my project with a sqlite database, however, as I deployed it through Heroku I changed my database to Postgresql. I followed the guidelines in https://cs50.readthedocs.io/heroku/ and my app deployed perfectly but when a function with SQL commands runs, the database and tables are not updated. Additionally, when the user is logged in but a SQL command runs, the app logs out. You can see my deployed app here https://desolate-temple-84845.herokuapp.com . When I run the app locally it works with the information the tables already have but don´t do changes to the database or tables, however the terminal registers the SQL commands in green.

I am experiencing the same problem that these users had: https://github.com/cs50/python-cs50/issues/118 . I tried to do what the users proposed, however they didn´t propose a solution with Postgres but with sqlalchemy. Unfortunately, I don´t know much about sqlalchemy so when some errors showed up I couldn´t do anything. Please try to help me to solve this problem with Postgres.

EDIT:

In order to link my database with the app I included

```
db = SQL("postgres://")
```

in which the postgres:// is the database URI.
This is the part of the code that includes SQL commands to register a user:

```
@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
"""Register user"""
if request.method == "POST":
    
    # Query database for username
    rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username;", username=request.form.get("username"))

    # Ensure username exists and password is correct
    if len(rows) == 1:
        flash("Taken username")
        return redirect("/register")
    else:
        numid = db.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users")
        numid = numid[0]["count"]
        numid += 1
        db.execute("BEGIN;")
        db.execute("INSERT INTO users (id, username, hash) VALUES(:id, :username, :hash);", id = numid, username = request.form.get("username"), hash = generate_password_hash(request.form.get("password")))
        db.execute("COMMIT;")
        return render_template("login.html")
else:
    return render_template("register.html")
```

Additionally, heroku logs do not show errors.

Comment: Without seeing any code examples this is going to be difficult to impossible to solve. Also any error messages from app and/or Postgres log. Generally when SQL is executed with no errors and another session does not see the data it is because there was no ```COMMIT``` issued for the transaction.

Comment: I have made an edit with a code example and more information. Thank you.

Comment: Most probably unrelated to your question, but using `count(*) + 1` is the worst possible method for generating unique IDs. For one it doesn't scale, but more importantly it doesn't work with concurrent transactions. Use an `identity` column instead.

Comment: Why are you manually running `begin` and `commit`? Doesn't Python (or the library you are using) support turning off autocommit mode? Does it work if you leave them out?

Comment: No, it doesn’t work if I leave them out.

Comment: The Github issue you pointed at is the problem. The [bug](https://github.com/cs50/python-cs50/pull/122)  has been fixed, it just has not been released. I would push them to get a release out so you can upgrade the package. For those following along this is caused by the mess that is this [sql](https://github.com/cs50/python-cs50/blob/develop/src/cs50/sql.py). A wrapper(sql) over a ORM(SQLAlchemy) over a driver(pscyopg2).

Comment: Oh thank you very much, I will do exactly that! @AdrianKlaver